# Python XML validation against Schema lxml

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, lxml

I am trying to validate an XML document against its XSD in Python.
I am currently following [this](https://emredjan.github.io/blog/2017/04/08/validating-xml/) tutorial.

I am able to read in my XML file without issue. However I need to provide an encoding type for the schema. Failing to do so results in a `'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81` error.

```
with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, xsd_filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as schema_file:
        schema_to_check = schema_file.read()
```

However, when I add the encoding etree is unable to parse the contents of the file? The error returned is `Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.`

```
xmlschema_doc = etree.parse(StringIO(schema_to_check))
```

I'm not sure I know what's going on. From the lxml site I get the impression that I should leave the encoding alone but I'm not sure why the tutorial works and mine doesn't?

My version of Python is 3.6.4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since amended my code to parse the file directly. This has fixed my issue and I am now able to validate my schema.

Code amendment:

```
with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, xsd_filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:                                                
     doc = etree.parse(f)
```